# How to create tweets with square website image cards?

Tags: twitter, ads

[Twitter's advertiser creative specifications](https://business.twitter.com/en/help/campaign-setup/advertiser-card-specifications.html) says that "1:1 aspect ratio is not available to self serve advertisers at this time.", suggesting that this is only possible in promoted tweets. but I have seen tweets with 1:1 website image cards that are not marked as "promoted"

[image]

Comment: This is going to be very hard to answer.  Only Twitter would know why "some" were allowed through and not others.  How many have you seen?  Are they from confirmed accounts, etc.?

Comment: So far only from one verified account: https://twitter.com/TheHSF/status/1005113974793252864 Also as you see the tweet's text doesn't have any URL and they are not marked as "promoted"

Comment: My basic inference from that is that the rules may not apply to certain non-profits, but again, just a guess.  It could be that large organizations can negotiate with Twitter over the details as well, which may not be on the table for smaller entities.  This is what makes the question almost impossible to answer without actually consulting Twitter.

Comment: If this was an ad or paid in anyway, per FTC regulations, they must disclose it by marking it with "promoted". so it seems to me they must be using some kind of free feature.